# Replace duplicate records set null ot empty in the column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, trending

**this is mysql query i want to set duplicate value as null or empty**

```
SELECT 
som.sale_invoice_id
,CONCAT(cm.first_name,cm.last_name) AS customername
,product_master.product_name 
FROM 
sale_invoice_master as som 
LEFT JOIN customer_master as cm 
     ON som.customer_id = cm.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN product_sale_item_master as soi 
     ON som.sale_invoice_id = soi.sale_invoice_id 
LEFT JOIN product_master   
     ON soi.product_id =product_master.product_id 
LEFT JOIN vehicle_master 
     ON soi.vehicle_id = vehicle_master.id
```

This is mycurrent result

| sale_invoice_id | customername | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JummakhanDilawarkhan | Apollo TYRE 16.9-28 12PR KRISHAK GOLD -D |
| 1 | JummakhanDilawarkhan | APOLLO TUBE 7.50x16 |
| 2 | PareshKhanchandani | Apollo TL 155R13 AMAZER XL 8PR |

i want this:

| sale_invoice_id | customername | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JummakhanDilawarkhan | Apollo TYRE 16.9-28 12PR KRISHAK GOLD -D |
|  |  | APOLLO TUBE 7.50x16 |
| 2 | PareshKhanchandani | Apollo TL 155R13 |

second duplicate row should be null or empty

Comment: This is something you shouldn't do in SQL. Let SQL report the complete data. If you want to display the data differently, do so in your app or Website. Handle GUI things in your GUI, not in your DBMS.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Asgar 10.4.21-MariaDB

Comment: I am positive that this can be achieved using variables and assignment operators(:=) but I strongly agree with @ThorstenKettner, *Handle GUI things in your GUI, not in your DBMS*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your data to work out with.
So what I have done is taken your current result as my primary data and used a query to produce your output:

I have mentioned it all in [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=979df062f690740e80f2ccd6472d1380)

Sure enough, you can modify this to use Window Functions as you are using MariaDB 10.4.
I have just mentioned a possible solution.

```
/*To create table*/
CREATE TABLE `sales_invoice_data` (
  `sales_invoice_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customername` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*to insert data*/
insert into `sales_invoice_data` (`sales_invoice_id`, `customername`, `product_name`) values('1','JummakhanDilawarkhan','Apollo TYRE 16.9-28 12PR KRISHAK GOLD -D');
insert into `sales_invoice_data` (`sales_invoice_id`, `customername`, `product_name`) values('1','JummakhanDilawarkhan','APOLLO TUBE 7.50x16');
insert into `sales_invoice_data` (`sales_invoice_id`, `customername`, `product_name`) values('2','PareshKhanchandani','Apollo TL 155R13');

/*to retrieve your OP*/
SELECT 
sales_invoice_id,
customerName,
product_name
FROM 
(SELECT 
(CASE WHEN sales_invoice_id=@running_sales_id THEN '' ELSE sales_invoice_id END)  sales_invoice_id,
(CASE WHEN customername=@running_customer THEN '' ELSE customername END) customerName,
product_name,
(CASE WHEN @running_sales_id=0 THEN @running_sales_id:=sales_invoice_id ELSE @running_sales_id:=@running_sales_id END) ,
(CASE WHEN @running_customer='' THEN @running_customer:=customername ELSE @running_customer:=@running_customer END) ,
@running_sales_id:=a.sales_invoice_id,
@running_customer:=customername
FROM 
(SELECT 
  s.sales_invoice_id ,
  s.customername,
  s.product_name,
  @running_sales_id:=0,
  @running_customer:=''
FROM
  `sales_invoice_data`  s) a ) final
  ;
```

Comment: this is worked.. thanks asgar bhai.. i just ran your query and exported it in excel csv file format with my custom data.


Thanks Bhai !

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would involve using MySQL's `LAG()` function. Here are the docs for it:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag